# onesignal sentTag() from admin group into spesific user

Tags: javascript, cordova, onesignal

I have group table and members in mysql database for example :

```
nogrup   nomember    active
1        1           1
1        2           1
1        3           0
```

in onesignal users dashboard as admin group (nogrup : 1) i will add tag for  nomember : 3 when "active field" become 1 with tag : sendTag("nogrup3", "1")
how to do this? sentTag parameter no PlayerID?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask